# Binomial random variable with coin flips. How do we get the formula $P(X=h) = \binom{n}{h}p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Let's say a coin produces $H$ (for heads) with probability $p$ (and thus it produces $T$ with probability $p-1$. Let $X$ denote the number of $H$s we see and let $h$ be an integer. Then, if we flip the coin $n$ times:

$P(X=h) = \binom{n}{h}p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$

I'm not quite understanding where this formula is coming from.

I can see that there are $\binom{n}{h}$ ways to choose a $h$-length subset of an $n$-length set (i.e. there are $\binom{n}{h}$ $n$-length sequences where we see $h$ heads), but why do we multiply that with the probability? Furthermore, why do we multiply the probabilities of heads and tails together?

I get that coin flipping is an independent repeated trial, but I'm not sure how to apply that here (or whether it's even relevant). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The probability of seeing the outcome HTHHT is $p^3(1-p)^2$: you need exactly three heads and exactly two tails. Multiplying by $\binom{5}{3}$ tells you how many ways it could happen that you get exactly three heads out of five flips (each of which occurs with probability $p^3(1-p)^2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can see that there are $\binom{n}{h}$ ways to choose a $h$-length subset of an $n$-length set (i.e. there are $\binom{n}{h}$ $n$-length sequences where we see $h$ heads),

Say, rather, $\tbinom n h$ is the count of ways to select $h$ elements from a set of $n$ distinct elements.   For example, the ways to select $h$ *positions* from a sequence of $n$ trials.

Thus $\tbinom nh$ is the count of ways to arrange $h$ heads among $n$ trial results.

> but why do we multiply that with the probability? Furthermore, why do we multiply the probabilities of heads and tails together?

$p$ is the probability that a trial will result in heads.   $p^h$ is the probability that $h$ independent trials will do so.   $(1-p)^{n-h}$ is the probability that $n-h$ independent trials will result in tails.   $p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$ is therefore the probability that the first $h$ independent trials will result in heads *and* the *next* $n-h$ independent trials will result in tails.

**However** that is for a *particular* arrangement of $h$ heads and $n-h$ tails.   We want the probability for *any* arrangement of that many heads and tails among $n$ trials.   So we must multiply by the count of such arrangements (since all arrangements are equally probable).$$\mathsf P(H{=}h) ~=~\dbinom n h p^h(1-p)^{(n-h)}\qquad\big[h\in\Bbb N, 0\leq h\leq n\big]$$

Comment: Hi there, sorry to dig up this old thread but I had to say thank you! I unfortunately lost track of this thread and so didn't read any of this at the time. This is really regrettable because even after two months these confusions of mine persisted. That is, up until I read this response! You made a lot of things explicit for me and that really helped my understanding a lot! Sorry again to dig up something so old, and thank you very much!

Comment: You are quite welcome. @JamesRonald

Answer (score 3):

The flips are independent, each with probability $p$ of being a head or $1-p$ of being a tail. Each of the $\binom{n}{h}$ choices of $h$ flips to be heads gives a head-tail sequence. Its probability is a product of $p$ and $1-p$ factors for heads and tails respectively, i.e. $p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$. (Or in @N.F.Taussig's words: "Since each of the $h$ heads has probability $p$ of occurring and each of the $n−h$ tails has probability $1−p$ of occurring, the probability that a particular sequence of $h$ heads and $n−h$ tails will occur is $p^h(1−p)^{n−h}$.") Together, these have probability $\binom{n}{h}p^h(1-p)^{n-h}$. As a sanity check,$$\sum_{h=0}^n\binom{n}{h}p^h(1-p)^{n-h}=(p+1-p)^n=1^n=1$$by the binomial theorem, so probabilities sum to $1$ as expected.

Comment: Your third sentence is not clear.  Since each of the $h$ heads has probability $p$ of occurring and each of the $n - h$ tails has probability $1 - p$ of occurring, the probability that a particular sequence of $h$ heads and $n - h$ tails will occur is $p^h(1 - p)^{n - h}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I've made an edit that credits you with that alternative phrasing.

Comment: This is really late, but sincere thanks for this response! This makes perfect sense and helps a lot, especially the sanity check using the binomial theorem. It's really nice to see when everything works out nicely. If only I had read this two months ago haha. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

After one throw, $H$ with probability $p$ and $T$ with probability $q$. In other words, $$1H: p, 0H: q.$$

After two throws, $HH$ with probability $pp$, $HT$ with probability $pq$, $TH$ with probability $qp$ and $TT$ with probability $qq$. In other words, $$2H: p^2, 1H: 2pq, 0H: q^2.$$

After three throws, $HHH$ with probability $p^3$, $HTH$ with probability $pqp$, $THH$ with probability $qpp$, $TTH$ with probability $q^2p$, $HHT$ with probability $p^2q$, $HTT$ with probability $pqq$, $THT$ with probability $qpq$ and $TTT$ with probability $qqq$. In other words, 
$$3H: p^3, 2H: 3p^2q, 1H: 3pq^2, 0H: q^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that the binomial coefficient counts the ways  a h-length subset of an n-length set.

Now we can calculate the probability that we flip $h$ heads first and then $n-h$ tails (one way):

$$\underbrace{111...111}_{\text{h times}}\underbrace{000...000}_{\text{n-h times}}$$

The probability $p^h\cdot (1-p)^{n-h}\quad (\color{blue}*)$.

In general we have $n$ independent **Bernoulli** distributed variables $Y_i$. So we calculate that

$$P(Y_1=1\cap Y_2=1 \cap \ldots \cap Y_h=1 \cap Y_{h+1}=0 \cap \ldots \cap Y_n=0)$$ Since $Y_i$´s are independent it is equal to $$P(Y_1=1)\cdot P(Y_2=1)\cdot \ldots \cdot P(Y_{h}=1)\cdot P(Y_{h+1}=0)\cdot \ldots \cdot P(Y_{n}=0)$$

With $P(Y_i=1)=p$ and $P(Y_i=0)=1-p$ we obtain $(\color{blue}*)$.

Answer (score 0):

> I get that coin flipping is an independent repeated trial, but I'm not sure how to apply that here (or whether it's even relevant).

Yes, the independence of trials is significant here (in binomial or miltinomial experiments).

If you flip a coin $n=1$ time, the possible outcomes are: $H$ or $T$. Let $X$ show the number of heads. Then:
$$P(X=0)=P(T)=\frac1q; \\
P(X=1)=P(H)=\frac1p.$$
If you flip a coin $n=2$ times, the possible outcomes are: $HH,HT,TH,TT$. Then:
$$\begin{align}P(X=0)&=P(T_1T_2)=P(T_1)\cdot P(T_2)=\frac1q\cdot \frac1q={2\choose 0}\left(\frac1p\right)^0\left(\frac1{q}\right)^2\\
P(X=1)&=P(H_1T_2)+P(T_1H_2)=P(H_1)\cdot P(T_2)+P(T_1)\cdot P(H_2)=\\
&=\frac1p\cdot \frac1q+\frac1q\cdot \frac1p={2\choose 1}\left(\frac1p\right)^1\left(\frac1{q}\right)^1\\
P(X=2)&=P(H_1H_2)=P(H_1)\cdot P(H_2)=\frac1p\cdot \frac1p={2\choose 2}\left(\frac1p\right)^2\left(\frac1{q}\right)^0\end{align}$$
Note: Because the trials are independent, $P(T_1T_2)=P(T_1)\cdot P(T_2|T_1)=P(T_1)\cdot P(T_2)$, that is, $P(T_2|T_1)=P(T_2)$, which is the condition for independent events.

I see you understand how to find the number of outcomes with $h$ heads using the combination formula.